# Error in connecting Eclipse to SQL Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

This is the syntax error

```
Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
 init
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
 the java.library.path: C:\Program Files   
 (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
 Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files
 (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files
 (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
 Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
 Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
 APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program
 Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
 Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
 Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
 Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
 Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
 Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
 Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web
 Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET
 Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
 Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
 Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLAB C32
 Suite\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
 Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
 SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
 Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
 Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\2013-2014 2nd
 Sem Files\Eclipsee\eclipse;;. Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
 [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
 property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:B2B' did not find a
 matching property. Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
 ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
 ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
 processed in 544 ms Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
 service Catalina Jun 10, 2014 5:15:51 PM
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
 Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 Jun 10, 2014 5:15:52 PM
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
 ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Jun 10, 2014 5:15:52 PM
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
 ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Jun 10, 2014 5:15:52 PM
 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 374
 ms com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax
 near '`'.
```

This is my code

```
package b2b.fishermall;

public class ConnectionString extends SqlStringCommands
{   
    public String getDriver()
    {       
       return "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";   
    }       
    public String getURL()
    {       
        return "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=B2B;integratedSecurity=true;";
    } 
    public String getUsername()
    {       
        return "";  
    }       
    public String getDbPassword()
    {       
        return "";  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't good.  Don't do this.

That's a lot of code when three static final Strings would do perfectly well.  Even better, you should externalize these things.

No username or password for database?  Oh, my.

If you're using Tomcat, the right thing to do is to use a JNDI connection pool.   Tomcat has [detailed docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) to show you how.

Let me take another guess: You're writing JSPs with scriptlets in them.  Another "don't do".  Learn JSTL if you must use JSPs.

I can't tell anything from that stack trace.  Is there anything else?

Comment: this project of mine works fine when my database is in MySQL. so i want to switch to SQL Server 2008, and this is the problem i encounter

Comment: ok thanks. maybe i should do it again from scratch. thanks for the tips!